# Upgrade of Python 3.9 with homebrew fails on High Sierra 10.13.6

Tags: macos, homebrew, upgrade, python

I'm obligated to upgrade my python on my brew installation so that I can upgrade many other software packages. Every time brew tries to make python (does from source), it gets stuck on make for days, really days. I have to quit, and I have resorted to having my current python pinned to get by with updating my casks. I don't know where to look to even begin to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: Homebrew doesn’t support High Sierra anymore, right? Might be time to switch to MacPorts, to take advantage of their unparalleled legacy support.

Comment: Yes, that’s true, but in the least I’d like to troubleshoot where I am with this before considering MacPorts.

Comment: "Where you are" is that Homebrew doesn't support High Sierra anymore and formulas are breaking! It's only going to get worse from here I'm afraid.

Comment: I see. So I can’t even install from Python.org and make brew ignore its own package since I’d have it installed that way?

Comment: You can try pinning the old python version. I doubt that dependent packages actually _need_ 3.9

Comment: I has been pinned, so I can move along with other packages not needing the latest Python, but brew warns me with so many packages that it requires the latest Python. It has become a huge issue with upgrading. I don’t know, maybe there’s a workaround to force brew to not use the latest? Pinning doesn’t help.

Comment: I have the same problem. Just by running `brew update`. I am not an expert with this. Currently trying with `brew install --verbose --debug python@3.9` to find out where it crashes. It hang at `make` for several hours.